# mysql not inserting through php cli

Tags: mysql, php5, php-cli

I have a simple php script which is ran from cli. I have tried many different variations of mysql code, but regardless, the line isnt inserted in the database even though php says it is....

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '***');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('***');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_log (to, from, subject, headers, message, source) VALUES ('1','2','3','4','5','6')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

php test.php
returns Last inserted record has id 0
and the same scripts work flawlessly through a web browser.

Things I have tried:

- I have changed file ownership to user that may effect it.
- 4-5 different INSERT codes

Comment: Add some more information to your question. For example the output of DESCRIBE email_log
Also fetch any errors mysql_query could raise, see example #1 in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: PHP5 has been [end of life since 2018](https://www.php.net/eol.php). Use a supported version of PHP.

Comment: Hey Gerald, thanks for your reply... I have switched to another installed ver 7.0. Same issue... Nothing reported in error.log. Did echo to email the line to be inserted and emailed ok... A conflict between cli and mysql?? I have run yest scripts, it seams to connect, It just completely ignores the actual insert.

Answer (score 0):

WOW... how unusual...No error messages, but I did a lot more digging and trouble shooting to find out, that "TO", "FROM" and "SOURCE" row names are on a MYSQL restricted/reserved list.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: The lesson? Don't expect mysql_query to work. Verify that it works by checking if it returns an error. Assumptions is the mother of all fuckups.

Answer (score 0):

- Do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface in PHP.  *Do* use `mysqli_*` instead.  (Or use PDO.)
- *Do* get the error message and display it.